# Undefined reference error _dl_stack_flags with gcc and pthreads

Tags: 10.10, gcc

Asked on StackOverflow, but the suggested solution involves using gcc 3.4.

Question with full details:

[_dl_stack_flags_error question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738000/undefined-reference-error-dl-stack-flags-with-gcc-and-pthreads)

However, my Ubuntu 10:

```
wade@wadesworld:~$ uname -a
Linux wadesworld 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5.028stab070.5ent #1 SMP Fri Sep 17 19:46:02 MSD 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

only allows gcc 4.1 as a minimum.

Has anyone seen / solved this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the information in your Stack Overflow question, I believe that the problem is due to you statically linking `libpthread`.  I put together the following trivial test program:

```
#include <pthread.h>

static void *
thread_start(void *arg)
{
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t thread_id = 0;
    void *result = NULL;

    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &thread_start, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id, &result);
}
```

If I compile it with `gcc -o test test.c -lpthread`, I get no errors.  If I attempt to link thread statically but everything else dynamically, I get a number of errors including the missing `_dl_stack_flags` error:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c -Wl,-Bstatic -lpthread -Wl,-Bdynamic
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libpthread.a(pthread_create.o): In function `allocate_stack':
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.13/nptl/allocatestack.c:451: undefined reference to `_dl_stack_flags'
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.13/nptl/allocatestack.c:595: undefined reference to `_dl_stack_flags'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libpthread.a(ptw-pause.o): In function `__pause_nocancel':
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.13/nptl/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.13/nptl/../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libpthread.a(nptl-init.o): In function `__pthread_initialize_minimal_internal':
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.13/nptl/nptl-init.c:277: undefined reference to `__libc_setup_tls'
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.13/nptl/nptl-init.c:295: undefined reference to `_dl_cpuclock_offset'
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.13/nptl/nptl-init.c:437: undefined reference to `_dl_init_static_tls'
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.13/nptl/nptl-init.c:439: undefined reference to `_dl_wait_lookup_done'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

You didn't list those additional errors, but I assume they showed up for you too.  I suspect that this error only occurs if you try to statically link `libpthread` but dynamically link `libc`.  If you dynamically link both things work, and I suspect that if you statically link both I suspect that would work too.  This isn't that surprising, since the two libraries are fairly closely related.

So I'd suggest adjusting your build configuration to dynamically link `libpthread`.

Comment: That was it!  Excellent!  Thanks so much for the help.  I'll link this answer to the stack overflow question too.

Comment: That's not the case for me. I get pretty the same errors whenever I statically link everything.

Comment: libc  is libgcc ?

Comment: @CSQGB: no. I mean glibc (i.e. the C standard library). The two libraries are closely tied, so you generally want to either have libc and libpthread both static or both dynamic.